# How do I enable core dumps in Void Linux?

Tags: core-dump, void-linux

Everything I see tells me to configure core dumps via `ulimit`, but Void doesn't have this command (at least not out of the box). I can't seem to find any relevant results to help me enable them.

I'm using Void because it has more security than distributions using `systemd`, and I'm trying to help some developers debug their program that runs on Void.

I need to enable core dumps to help them get proper debugging information.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we search the repository for packages related to the keyword, dump, we find among the results a package named ProcDump. The package description claims that the software "provides a way to create core dumps."

```
xbps-query -Rs dump
```

Above, the `-R` switch asks `xbps-query` to search repositories, and the `-s` switch searches for matches on a string or regular expression. Installation is accomplished as shown below, using the `-S` (synchronize) switch.

```
xbps-install -S ProcDump-for-Linux
```

This action also installs dependencies: `libreadline8`, `gdbm`, `sqlite`, `libffi`, `python3`, and `gdb`.

According to it's [website](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProcDump-for-Linux), "ProcDump is a Linux reimagining of the classic ProcDump tool from the Sysinternals suite of tools for Windows. ProcDump provides a convenient way for Linux developers to create core dumps of their application based on performance triggers." Documentation and examples are given by the developers, and a manual is included in the package, `man 8 procdump`.

Answer (score 2):

`ulimit` is a shell builtin, the shells void comes with have it.